# how can i stop some words/letters from being swapped in php?

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I am using php to swap text from one textarea and display in another, and most of it works, but sadly some parts dont.

I am using `str_ireplace` and then so far, 60 different words, with many more to come. A couple of examples of my problem are:

```
old - auld
old man - gadgie
```

if you look above, the first word is the unswapped and the second is the new word. However, if i put old man in the text, it would come as "auld man" instead of "gadgie".

I know that this may be because i have declared "old-auld" before "old man - gadgie"

but another problem is that:

```
yes - aye
no - nar
```

Again, first word is original, second is after swap. If i were to write "yesterday" it would be displayed "ayeterday" or if i had "nose" it would be "narse"

Is there anyway to change ONLY "yes" on its own and not if it is part of another word?

And is there any way to have "old man" and "old" as separate replacements?

Hope that makes sense

My code for `str_ireplace`:

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php" >
<textarea name="status2" cols="50" rows="5"/>
<?php echo str_ireplace(array  ('old','awkward','all','again','behind','along','alright','hello','among','children','yes','child','kids','food','barnard castle','beer','book','blow','beautiful','bird','burst','brown','burn','boots','came','nice','cold','church','clothes','stick','dirty','clever','cloth','cow','crow','stool','crown','pigeon','dad','darlington','dead','do','devil','dont','do not','durham','down','drown','punch','ditch','eye','fall','trouble','condition','four','stupid','old man','go','going','jumper','give over','grandad','hold','get away','home'), 
array ('auld', 'aakwad', 'aall','agyen','ahint','alang','alreet','alreet','amang','bairns','aye','bairn','bairns','bait','barney','beor','beuk','blaa','bonny','bord','borst','broon','bourn','byeuts','cam','canny','card','chorch','claes','clag','clarty','clivvor','cloot','coo','craa','cracket','croon','cushat','da','darlo','deed','dee','deil','divvent','divvent','dorham','doon','droon','dunsh','dyke','Eee','faa','fash','fettle','fower','gaumless','gadgie','gan','gannin','ganzie','giveower','granda','haad','hadaway','hyem'),$status); ?> 

</textarea><br>
```

As i said, there are 60+ words.

I didn't add my code initially as i thought it may not have been relevant.

Comment: Some actual code would be a big help.

Comment: `preg_replace`? maybe, you're gonna want regex to check for either a space after each of these words, or the end of the line

Comment: i just tried using preg_replace. i used this preg_replace("/(\b)yes(\b)/", "aye", $status); but it still shows 'ayeterday'

Comment: now i feel like an idiot! i didnt realise i already had a replace when i was testing, so no matter what i changed it done it wrong, now i have removed it and used preg_replace it works brilliant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About first part. You should replace more specific word first. i.e "old man", and then "man" or use [strtr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php)

```
<?php
$trans = array("h" => "-", "hello" => "hi", "hi" => "hello");
echo strtr("hi all, I said hello", $trans);
?>
The above example will output:
hello all, I said hi
```

About the whole words. You may look to regexps (and `\b` in particularly)